# Program fails as Linux systemctl service but runs when called directly

Tags: linux, service, systemctl

I have a script (a web listener) which runs on its own without problem:

```
> /usr/bin/python3 /home/[user]/scripts/CrossPlatform/workflow_trigger.py
```

I already have a different service that works well. So, I copied that file under a new name /etc/systemd/system/my_workflow.service:

```
Description=My Service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/[user]/scripts/CrossPlatform/workflow_trigger.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The ExecStart line is a direct copy of the command that runs successfully.

I then run:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start my_service.service
```

It runs without a message. Unfortunately:

```
systemctl status my_service.service
```

Shows:

```
my_service.service - My Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my_service.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-07-01 10:57:35 CDT; 958ms ago
  Process: 2722 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/[user]/scripts/CrossPlatform/workflow_trigger.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2722 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

The OS is:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
```

What might be a fix?
Many thanks,
Bogdan

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an access issue. The service was set to run as User=root while dropping data (by default) to the individual user's folder. Fixing the save path to a more generic directory or changing the User to home folder's owner fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First move ExecStart right after [service] and remove user=root from services. Also mentioned ExecStop in services.

```
Description=My Service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/[user]/scripts/CrossPlatform/workflow_trigger.py
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```